# Unable to update the next empty cells of closed workbook

Tags: vba, excel

My requirement is
1) To open a existing Excel workbook
2) Identify the next empty row and enter time stamp to that row
3) Save and Close the Excel work book
To achieve this I used below code:

```
 Sub UpdateReport()  
    Dim directory As String, fileName As String  
    Dim FirstBlankCell As Range  
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False  
    directory = "C:\Users\Desktop\Excel_sheets\"  
    fileName = Dir(directory & "Reports.xls")  
    Set wbr = Workbooks.Open(directory & fileName, ReadOnly:=False)  
    Set FirstBlankCell = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)  
    FirstBlankCell.Activate  
    myTimeStamp = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd_hhmmss")  
    FirstBlankCell.Value = myTimeStamp  
    wbr.Saved = True  
    'wbr.Close True  
    End Sub
```

Problem I am facing is this code updates the sheet only if its open and also it overwrites the values.
I want the time-stamp to be set in next empty cell rather than over writing the old cell without keeping the excel open

Comment: **Why are you opening the same file twice ??**

Comment: @Gary'sStudent: copy paste issue, corrected now :)

Comment: Does the workbook contain only a single worksheet??  If no, should you not select a sheet before putting a value in a cell ??

Comment: Yes, it has only one sheet.

Comment: You never actually **Save** wbr.  You only say it is saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following piece of code should fulfill your requirement:

```
Sub UpdateReport()
Dim directory As String, fileName As String
Dim FirstBlankCell As Range
directory = "C:\Users\raj.kamal\Documents"
fileName = "stack1.xlsx"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ExcelAppl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(directory & "/" & fileName, ReadOnly:=False)
wb.Activate
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
Set FirstBlankCell = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
myTimeStamp = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd_hhmmss")
ws.Activate
FirstBlankCell = myTimeStamp
wb.Save
wb.Close
ExcelAppl.Quit
Set wb = Nothing
Set ExcelAppl = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem. Can you please explain what was I missing?